# Proper way to use Pageable sorting with nested objects when sending requests from frontend to backend?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting, jpa, pageable

I have many tables with sortable headers in the frontend. When any of them is clicked, a request similar to

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/items/?page=0&size=10&sort=item.type.name,asc&itemId=4
```

is sent to the backend where it gets automatically mapped to a Pageable object and goes to a Repository.
Notice the `item.type.name` part. If relationships are relatively simple, this works but does not feel like a good way to do it.

What if I need to compare against a property of an object which is inside a collection?

What is the best practice to sort by values from lists like `errors` in the `item.order.errors.name` example, when the relationship is one to many?

I'm afraid writing sorting headers like `item.type.name` or even `a.b.c.d.e.f.g` in a bad scenario, creates a very tight coupling where it will be difficult to change or refactor code in the future without breaking anything.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but I do see that the Pageable's [Sort object](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html) is something that can be subclassed. Maybe there's a way there, or even an existing subclass that would help. I can't tell from a quick glance. The [TypedSort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.TypedSort.html) maybe?

Comment: If you need to refactor the backend, you need to frontend also. If you don't want to then just send the param `sortParam=itemTypeName` and manage in the backend when needed and create pageable/sort object manually.